# How to implement java or android logic to wait for additional user input for a certain amount of time before executing?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app that can stream TV channels from a Satellite dish. The app's media player implements the MotionEvent class such that when I swipe from left to right on the screen, the app sends a request to the server to stream the next channel in the list. The server can only take one request at a time but I want to give the user the ability to swipe multiple times to signify they want to change the channel more than once. It takes 5~8 seconds for the channel to switch, and in that time period, I will have a spinner show on the screen, while the current channel keeps streaming

I would like to implement a wait timer for, let's say 1 second, that allows for additional swipes by the user before sending that request. For example, I am currently watching channel 1. I swipe right to switch to channel 2. In that one second wait timer, I swipe again, which updates the request to change the channel to the next to next channel. This also resets the wait timer, so that it will wait for another second to see if the user makes additional swipes.

Here is my code, in my PlayerActivity class. This method will call onSwipeRight when the user swipes right on the screen and swipe left when user swipes left on the screen. Swiping left will request the server for the previous channel .

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = event.getX();
                float diffX = x2 - x1;
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Min_distance && player_details.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    if (diffX > 0){
                        onSwipeRight();
                    }else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }else {
                    toggleControlsVisibility();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

The onSwipeRight() logic is like so :

```
public void onSwipeRight(){

switch_index = Integer.valueOf(contentManager.readData("current_channel_position", playerActivity.this));

        previous_major = majorList.get(switch_index);
        previous_minor = minorList.get(switch_index);
        previous_name = nameList.get(switch_index);

        if (switch_index == 0){
            switch_index = majorList.size() - 1;
        }else{
            switch_index = switch_index - 1;
        }

        contentManager.saveData(String.valueOf(switch_index),"current_channel_position", playerActivity.this);

        switch_major = majorList.get(switch_index);
        switch_minor = minorList.get(switch_index);
        switch_name = nameList.get(switch_index);


        final String tuner = tunelink+"Major="+switch_major+"&Minor="+switch_minor+MainActivity.resolution;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String playlive ="";
                String tune_response = tuneConnection.get_response(tuner);
                if (tune_response.contains("successful")){

                    do {
                        String hlsstatus_response = hlsstatusConnection.get_response(gethlslink);
                        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<hls_link>(.+?)</hls_link>").matcher(hlsstatus_response);
                        while (matcher.find()) {

                            playlive = matcher.group(1);
                        }

                        playlink = "http://" + Main2Activity.ip + "/" + playlive;
                        Log.d(tag, "Swipte right hls response: " + playlink);

                    }while (Objects.equals(playlive, "none"));

                    player.stop();
                    if (airingList.get(switch_index)!= null) {
                        String response = streamConnection.get_response(playlink);
                        if (response != null) {
                            thumbnailConnection.get_response(airingList.get(switch_index));
                        }
                    }else {
                        String response = streamConnection.get_response(playlink);
                        Message mg = Message.obtain();
                        mg.obj = "no airing";
                        noairing_handler.sendMessage(mg);
                    }
                }



            }
        }).start();       


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a timer function before you execute additional commands.

Here is the link to implementation tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_timer.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement this. On the server, you could check if a request is still being handled and cancel it when the client makes the call to obtain a New Channel.

Far easier in my opinion would be to set a ~2 second delay after a Channel switch for example, before the swiperight event is allowed to make  the API call. This way, once the user swipes right (fast enough) they have x amount of time to swiperight again before the Channel 'locks in' and starts loading.

Comment: How would you set that 2 second delay, code wise? I've tried searching for a solution but all I can find is Thread.sleep() and I don't think that applies here since I want it to still be listening for touch events.

Comment: Once the swipe right event is called, run a timer with x delay which starts the runnable. If there is another swipe right event before the timer runs out and starts the runnable, kill the timer and reset it.

Comment: Thanks! Ashish had the same answer but its only fair I give him the Correct Answer since he replied before.